# prevent jQuery form submit if validation fail

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

Hi I'm trying to prevent this AJAX submit form function when a validation fails on one of one of the various inputs.

Edit: What I want to know exactly is what I need to include in //Adult age validation and var handleFormSubmit to stop saveForm($('#quotecriteria_form')); and performAjaxSubmit(formData, url); from occurring.

Submit function:

```
  var handleFormSubmit = function( e ) {
e.preventDefault();

var $submit = $('button[type="submit"]');
$submit.addClass('loading');

// Save the contents of the form to session cookie
saveForm($('#quotecriteria_form'));

var formData = $('#quotecriteria_form').serialize();
var url = $('#quotecriteria_form').attr('action');
performAjaxSubmit(formData, url);
}
```

validation functions initialized:

```
IndexPageFunctions = {
init: function() {
//Validate date range
this.validateToDate();
this.validateFromDate();
//Validate adult age
this.validateAdultAge0();
this.validateAdultAge1();
this.validateAdultAge2();
this.validateAdultAge3();
//Validate child age
this.validateChildAge0();
this.validateChildAge1();
this.validateChildAge2();
this.validateChildAge3();
this.validateChildAge4();
this.validateChildAge5();
this.validateChildAge6();
this.validateChildAge7();
this.validateChildAge8();
},
```

One of the many validation functions:

```
//Adult age validation
validateAdultAge0: function() {
    $('button[type="submit"]').on('click', function() {
var inputVal = parseInt( $("input[name='adultAges[0]']").val());
if (inputVal < 18) {
    $("input[name='adultAges[0]']").css("border-color","red");
$("div#under18").addClass('show').removeClass('hidden');
}
        });
},
```

Comment: I don't see where you are using your validation functions, but you'll probably need to return `true` or `false` from them if the calling method needs to know if validation passed or not.  Show us the code that calls the validation methods.

Comment: And where is the problem?

Comment: Great, you've shown your intentions and some code, but haven't provided any indication of what's wrong or asked any questions

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what I need to include in //Adult age validation and var handleFormSubmit to stop saveForm($('#quotecriteria_form')); and performAjaxSubmit(formData, url); from occuring

Comment: update the post with your issues so it is readily visible to all

Comment: Does every validation function looks like `validateAdultAge0 `? If yes, Don't repeat yourself!

Comment: done. Hope I'm making sense.

Comment: @localghost yeah validateAdultAge0-3 and validateChildAge0-8 all look very similar but I am a noob to jquery...

Comment: You'd do well to look into something like [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) or [WebShim](http://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/)

Comment: @Igor yes that's correct I need to know what to add into the function to stop the form submit now.

Comment: @Tomanow can't use validation plugin on this project

Comment: to be honest you have nothing to track the  overall validation  state of the form through all these different functions

Comment: @charlietfl how would I go about creating something that did?

Comment: Without seeing all the code or knowing your capabilites, would suggest putting everything in one submit handler that can keep track of errors , either in array or just a boolean. Then when get to end of all the elements, return false if there are errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a boolean array outside the scope of all functions with an index for each input element:

```
var valid = [false,false,false...];
```

Set the original value to false if blank input should be considered invalid or true if the field is optional. In each of your validation handlers (like validateAdultAge0) change the corresponding flag accordingly. For example if you decide to map the validity of age0 to the 0th index then:

```
if (inputVal < 18) {
    $("input[name='adultAges[0]']").css("border-color","red");
    $("div#under18").addClass('show').removeClass('hidden');
    valid[0] = false;
}else{
    valid[0] = true;
}
```

Like someone in the comments pointed out, if the logic is the same for each of these functions you should be using an argument to specify the target input, not creating an entirely new function but I won't get into that here.

In handleFormSubmit you'll just need to check if all the flags in the valid array are set to true, if any one is false you can return:

```
for(var i=0;i<valid.length;i++){
    if(!valid[i]){
        return;
    }
}
```